# javascript: How to add div to table cell dynamically?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, charts

I have a table which is filling dynamically via SignalR+knockout.js

```
<table id="infoTable" border="0" class="table table-striped">
    <thead style="cursor:pointer">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
            <td data-bind="click: $parent.toggleSort, text: title"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: machines -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: machineName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: cpu"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: memUsage"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: memTotal"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: memPercent"></td>
            <td>
                <div class="demo-container">
                    <div id="placeholder1" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to somehow add a new cell and draw chart (flotchart.org) with MemPercent to this cell.

How to add this?

In a static case the chart can be made this way:

```
var container1 = $("#placeholder1");
        var plot1 = $.plot(container1, dataSeries, {
            series: {
                shadowSize: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            xaxis: {
                show: false
            }
    });

function update() {
            plot1.setData(series);
            plot1.draw();
            setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
        }

        update();
```

My questions:
1. how to add cell with chart dynamically?
2. how to access any chart containers during the update?

Thnx.

Comment: Do you have to add another td dynamically?

Comment: Simply saying: I'd like to add chart to the table row. Probably I can add div with the same name but how to access during the update? This is a sample from this blog http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/real-time-system-resource-monitor-with-signalr-mvc-knockout-and-webapi/#comment-3293

Comment: I am writing my solution. You also need to take some data from your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add chart to the table row with jQuery

```
$('tbody').append('<tr><td data-bind="text: machineName"></td><td data-bind="text: cpu"></td><td data-bind="text: memUsage"></td><td data-bind="text: memTotal"></td><td data-bind="text: memPercent"></td><td><div class="demo-container"><div id="placeholder1" class="demo-placeholder"></div></div></td></tr>');
```

I think you will need to enter this code inside a loop.

To take the data to put in the cell, you can use an [Ajax Call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ok, how I can do it in my script? There are rows adding dynamically. See the 1st script <!-- ko foreach: machines -->